# Can't understand partial derivatives identity

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying multivariable calculus, and can't understand this. Could someone derive/explain this identity?
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -1$$

Edit: $x$, $y$ , $z$ are real-valued functions with multiple variables $$x = x(y,z)$$ $$y = y(x,z)$$ $$z = z(x,y)$$

Comment: You should give a little bit more context... What are $x$, $y$ and $z$ here?

Comment: I think this has to do with wedge products and differential forms. When you switch the order if multiplication you make the answer negative, so for example, $dxdy$=$-dydx$.

Comment: This is the [triple product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule).